# PHP unknown encoding with accents

Tags: php, character-encoding

im having really troubles with some folders/files reading with php.

I do a scandir o a folder and a specific file inside have a name with these word: "BAILÉN". When i do a "echo" it shows "BAILE´N".
The big problem is php dont recognize the file. The functions is_file, is_dir, file_exist, rename, scandir... fails.

I tried utf8_encode, decode, iconv with a lot of charsets and nothing work.

This is a file with the name:

https://mega.nz/#!w34XXa7Z!89NYKRBXkx3u-uaSYZd_E2LijDdzIf3trIUu8UrHE18

PHP Version 5.6.12

Thank you very much (sorry if my english is not good)

---

edit:

If anyone was interested.

One of my partner developed a small C# app to replace problematic chars (C# function recognize the files)

i was able to replace the problematic char with hex2bin and bin2hex. But no matter what i did none of the php function recognize de file.

I think php function have problems with that characters and theres nothing i can do.

Comment: the bad É byte code is: 69 204 129, (hex 45 cc 81) thats an E + COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are encountering the joy of Unicode canonical représentation.

There are more ways to represent the "É" character.  either `U+00C9`in utf-8 'C3 89' **Capital E with acute accent**.
or `U+0045 U+0301`  **Capital E + Diacritic mark acute accent** Utf-8 '45 cc 81'. You are in the second case.

There is a way to check this issue : try looking for the  "BAILÉN" using the U+00C9 point code  for the "É"

There is a class available since PHP 5.3.0 and its static function that aims at resolving those issues :
http://php.net/manual/en/class.normalizer.php
http://php.net/manual/en/normalizer.normalize.php

By the way, the filename storage mechanism is file-system and OS-dependent. Results may differ if you are running the code on Linux on ext*fs, *BSD on whatver, or Windows with NTFS.

Comment: The "joy" XD. I think i dont have install normalizer in php. I´ll try next week to play with replace using U+00C9 and U+0045 U+0301. Thank you very much. Still don´t know why php dont recognize it.